# Use previews of the .NET Core SDK not working anymore

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm using the new feature `previews of the .NET Core SDK` for more than six month without any problems.

Today I wanted to create a new project solution with a `WPF App (.NET Core)`. But everytime I want to create the project (or add the project into an existing solution), I get the following exception:

> Switch to "Extras" - "Options" - "Envirenment" - "Previewfeatures" to create this project and activate "Use previews of the .NET Core SDK"
>
> [image]

**The feature is already enabled (since it is working for more than 6 month). I have also tried to un/check again (including visual studio restarts).**

Anyone got same problem or some tip to get it working again?

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to run .NET Core 3, you need the preview version of Visual Studio too. Or wait until Monday when it's all going to be released properly

Comment: Is this a new information? If you have a look at https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0 they wrote: `Supports Visual Studio 2019 (v16.3, latest preview)` So I'm a bit confused about that. But as you already said, maybe it is solved on monday 

Comment: See the bit where it says "latest preview"?

Comment: Ah damn, my fault! ‍♂️ I have vs `v16.2.5` installed and `.net-core v3.0.0-preview6` still supported vs `16.2` (the newer version doesn't). I will install the old version, then the problem should be fixed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DavidG already wrote, the latest `.net core preview v3.0.0-rc1` doesn't supported `visual studio 16.2.5` anymore.

[image]

After installing an older version (the latest which supports `v16.2`) `v3.0.0-preview6`, everything was working as before.

[image]

source: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0

Comment: I'm glad found this answer sooner rather than later... upgrading VS2019 on the way!